# Geometrically demonstrating that the integral of $\pi r^2$ matches the volume of a cone with radius and height of $r$

Tags: integration, geometry

Does anyone have a geometric demonstration that the integral of $\pi r^2$ matches the volume of a cone with radius and height of $r$?

Comment: yess!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Try asking it the other way around. "Why is the derivative of the volume of a cone with height and radius $r$, the same as $\pi r^2$?"

Comment: Where do you want to go?

Comment: So if you increase $r$ by a small amount say $r+h$, what will happen to the shape of the cone? The top of the cone (the part with height $r$) remains unchanged and we then extend the cone with something, which is proportional to the area of the bottom of the cone. The bottom of the cone is a circle with radius r.

Comment: Interesting! Can I find a more imaginary explanation?